# How to redirect my application to https directly on Heroku?

Tags: .net, angular, heroku, http-redirect

I have an application where I need to secure it with https. I have certificate on Heroku(paid version and certificate is automatically managed) and also, it writes that my app can be found at https://www.minibrocki.ch. But also, when I write name of my application in browser it gives me without https. I don't want that, I want to every time goes to https(force redirection to https). So, my question is, can I do that directly on Heroku and If I can, how to do that?
Here is screenshot of my Heroku settings:

This is when I have just one domain:

[image]

And this happens when I want to insert new domain:

[image]

Comment: on IIS i do this using a web.config file.  it looks like Heroku runs on Apache.  maybe it would be helpful to see if there is a config file that Apache will honor for url redirects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku answered that very nicely in their documentation for each environment:
[Can Heroku force an application to use SSL/TLS? - Yes it can](https://help.heroku.com/J2R1S4T8/can-heroku-force-an-application-to-use-ssl-tls)

If you want to take a deeper look into opportunities to configure Custom Domain Names for Apps [Custom Domain Names for Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains)

Comment: @Atenica: Does that answers your question?